# What is the difference between mapped classes and schema-derived classes?

Tags: java, jaxb

```
JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" )
```

The `JAXBContext` instance is initialized from a list of colon-separated Java package names. Each Java package contains JAXB mapped classes, schema-derived classes and/or user annotated classes.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, "JAXB mapped classes" are classes mapped for JAXB. Typically these classes will contain JAXB annotations, but there are also other ways of providing JAXB mappings.

Schema-derived classes are classes which were generated ("derived") from some schema. Typically generated using XJC from an XML Schema.

User annotated classes are classes where JAXB annotations were added by the developer.

I would see "schema-derived classes" and "user annotated classes" as subsets of "JAXB mapped classes".